# How to remove all element after a specific element of array?

Tags: javascript

Below is my array....

```
["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]
```

What can I do to get a array back like ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]

for example, if the first element is "AAA", I want to delete all element after second "AAA"(second "AAA" also remove)

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to filter unique elements from an array?

Comment: `arr.slice(0, indexOfSpecificElement + 1)` or `array.length = indexOfSpecificElement + 1;`.

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu What I want is to only get first pattern of a array. like"AAA","BBB","CCC"

Comment: let say, if the first element is "AAA", I want to delete all element after second "AAA"(second "AAA" also remove)

Comment: Ok so you want to break the array if that repeat ?

Comment: yes, depends on first element.

Comment: [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: So you don't care that your input array doesn't just repeat the same three items - it ends with "DDD", which appears only once, but you don't want "DDD" in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily using **indexOf** and **slice** methods of array in javascript.

```
var arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];
var firstElem = arr[0];
var secondIndex = arr.indexOf(firstElem, 1);

// Output: ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
var newArr = (secondIndex != -1) ? arr.slice(0, secondIndex) : arr;
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4f25wyaj/2/

Comment: This is good, but note that if the first element *doesn't* repeat the result will be an array keeping all of the original elements except the last one.

Comment: @nnnnnn—but that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @RobG - The OP doesn't say what to do if the first element doesn't repeat, but it seems unlikely that removing just the last item via `.slice(0,-1)` would be the right thing in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`, reference first element of array to check if the value has been iterated

```js
var arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]

var again = false;

arr = arr.filter(function(el, index) {
  return !again && (again = index > 0 && el === arr[0], !again);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Why not  `var newArr = arr.slice(arr.indexOf(arr[0], 1))`.

Comment: @RobG _"Why not `var newArr = arr.slice(arr.indexOf(arr[0], 1))`"_  Appears to return `["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]`?

Comment: @Bergi `this` passed to `.map()` or `.filter()` callback returns object, not value. `arr = arr.filter(function(el, index) {
  return !again && (again = index > 0 && el === arr[0], !again);
})` returns same result

Comment: The proper fix for that would to use a strict function or loose comparison, not `valueOf`. And yes, passing in a context is pretty superfluous when you can just refer to the `arr[0]` element directly.

Comment: @Bergi Updated post to use `arr[0]`. What is issue with using `valueOf`?

Comment: Ah, sliced the wrong end! `arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf(arr[0], 1))` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Faster implementation (Better for short or medium size arrays):

```
var a = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];

// Faster implementation:
// (Better for short or medium size arrays)
var b = a.filter((function(){
    var idx = {};
    var cont = true; // Continue
    return function (item){
        if (! cont) return false;
        if (idx[item]) return cont = false;
        return idx[item] = true;
    };
})());

console.log(b);
// [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' ]
```

Implementation with minimal memory waste (but highly unefficient):

```
// Minimal memory waste implementation:
var b = a.filter((function(){
    var cont = true; // Continue
    return function (item, i){
        if (! cont) return false;
        if (a.slice(0, i).filter(x=>x==item).length) return cont = false;
        return true;
    };  
})());

console.log(b);
// [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' ]
```

Of course, there is infinite intermediate approaches (depending on your needings). But, If you donsn't need to parse **HUGE** arrays, the best solution is to use the first approach: Index will be freed by garbage collector as soon as filter process finishes and, in fact, if you are lucky and repetition happen early, then no much memory will be used ;-)

Comment: Instead of `filter(…).length` you you want to use `some(…)`. Or just use `indexOf`, it even takes a starting position.

Comment: For huge arrays, an even better solution would be not to use `filter` at all, because you likely wouldn't need to iterate through the whole array. Just stop when you have the slice you need.

Comment: Maybe yes or maybe not: `.some()` was standarizend in ECMA-262 (early June 2016) so, depending on where you want to execute it, you would need a polyfill. Even, of course, some() will stop at first match avoiding a bit of extra process at the end.

Comment: Both `filter` and `some` were standardised at the same time, in ES5 (2011) - and had been around in FF since 2005.

Comment: About your second comment, You are totally right. This was only a fast rewrite of the first approach (which is the best for me in most cases). But if we need to parse an huge array, then we probably should not only stop at first match, but totally avoid not strictly necessary function calls. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty using jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

[each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)  goes through the array and adds elements to new array until a duplicate of the first element is found.

```
var arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];
var newArray = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, newArray) === -1) 
      newArray.push(el);
    else if (el == arr[0])
      return false
});
arr = newArray;
// Formatted array is in "arr"
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Hardly quick. Why on earth would you use jQuery *each* when the built–in *forEach* is available? If you want IE8 support, you have to go back to jQuery 1.12. Better to use a [*polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: You have 68k reputation, you should know better that it's not about optimization, it's about solving the problem. This is not "the best solution". This is a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Though Your question is not fully clear
but still as per my understanding I am providing following solutions

```
Solution 1:
 Assumption: You have a list of input and a pointer which shows the last index till you want to pick the input data.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input[] = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" };
        String output[]= new String[5];
        int stopByIndex =3;

        for(int i=0;i<stopByIndex;i++){
            output[i]=input[i];
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }


 Solution 2:
Assumption: Print elements which occurred multiple times:

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input[] = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" };
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Integer> keyWithCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int stopByIndex = 3;

    for (String str : input) {
        if (keyWithCount.containsKey(str)) {
            keyWithCount.put(str, keyWithCount.get(str) + 1);
        } else {
            keyWithCount.put(str, 1);
        }
    }

    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> itr = keyWithCount.entrySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Integer> entry = itr.next();

        if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
            output.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC",     "DDD"];

arr.splice(3)
```

Comment: How did you guess that first repetition will always be at fourth position? :LOL:

Comment: Why not just try `var arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];`? That gets us the result without any inperformant splicing.